# "Http failure response for https://xxxx.xxx/sub/spot/1: 401 Unauthorized",

Tags: angular, nativescript, response, http-status-code-401, http-error

I have a problem with my code.

I have:

- HTTP Method POST
- Endpoint https://xxxx.xxx/sub/spot/{spotNo}
- Header
  Content-Type: application/json and X-TOKEN:
- Route parameters: spotNo

For this I create a service like that:

```
public Sub(spotNo: string): Observable<Subscription> {
    return this.httpclient.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.spot + '/' + spotNo), {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'X-TOKEN': 'eyJ0e',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
        observe: 'response'
    }).pipe(map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        return new Subscription(response)
      }, error => {
        console.log('err', error)
    }));
}
```

and in component I subscribe with this function

```
subscribespot() {  
    this.subservice.Sub(this.spotsid).subscribe(
        result => {
            console.log('result', result)
        },
        error => {
            console.log('errorr', error)
        }
    );
}
```

In Postman I get correct response.

In console show this error:

```
JS: errorr {
JS:   "headers": {
JS:     "normalizedNames": {},
JS:     "lazyUpdate": null
JS:   },
JS:   "status": 401,
JS:   "statusText": "Unauthorized",
JS:   "url": "https://xxxx.xxx/sub/spot/1",
JS:   "ok": false,
JS:   "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
JS:   "message": "Http failure response for https://xxxx.xxx/sub/spot/1: 401 Unauthorized",
JS:   "error": {
JS:     "status": "failed",
JS:     "message": "Wrong number of segments"
JS:   }
JS: }
```

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with the used JWT token. Are you sure that you are using the correct one in both cases?

Comment: Yes, I 'm sure, token is correct

Comment: Please share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced.